# Writing to a JSON file using c++?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Suppose I have a JSON object as follows :

```
{
    "Tickets": [
        {
            "Name" : "Alice Parker",
            "Age" : "21",
        }
    ]
}
```

The above text is from a Names.json file.
I want to append more objects into Tickets Array.
Suppose I have another Object as follows:

```
{
    "Name" : "Tony Stark",
    "Age" : "21",
}
```

I want to add this object also in the array. How can I to it and save the file..
The resultant File should now look like this -

```
{
    "Tickets": [
        {
            "Name" : "Alice Parker",
            "Age" : "21",
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Tony Stark",
            "Age" : "21",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using [This Package to use JSON in C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

how can I add more objects in the array and save it to a File called Names.json

My code so far:

```
std::ofstream output_file("TESTING.json");
json out;
out["Tickets"] = NAMES;
output_file << out.dump(4);
output_file.close();
```

I printed "NAMES" and it looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "Name" : "Alice Parker",
        "Age" : "21",
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Tony Stark",
        "Age" : "21",
    }
]
```

Comment: The first two examples for that package explain how to do both things. What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: @KenY-N Please Check I've added the code which I tried.

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question. Consider using [JSONCPP](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation here](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a3405d38087e13994a5a4556065b0be6d.html), something like:

```
json theData;
// read from file to theData
theData["Tickets"] += R("
{
    "Name" : "Tony Stark",
    "Age" : "21",
}
)"_json;

// or .push_back()
```

Might work. Without sample code, though, I cannot test.